# Sortable Save Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

I'm using nested model forms in Rails, with a Questions and answers app, similar to the Ryan Bates one, here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised.

Now, I want to make the questions sortable, and then save their position when I go to show them in show.html.erb.

So my views look like:

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
  <ul class='sortable'>
     <%= render 'question_fields', f: builder %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add Question", f, :questions %>
```

_question_fields.html.erb:

```
<li>
  <%= f.label :content, "Question" %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :content %><br />
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
  <%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove Question" %>
</li>
```

my jquery is just a simple:

```
$(".sortable").sortable();
```

the helper is:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
  new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
  id = new_object.object_id
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
    render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
  end
  link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
end
```

I've found similar SO questions about saving via Ajax (using Sortable's `serialize()`), but I'm really just looking for a solution to save without having to use AJAX.

Comment: what is the html being rendered

Comment: @Rooster, I added the error that occurred to the question. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @the_ can you paste the html code returned in your browser? (the paginator html)

Comment: @MrMins, there is no paginator? Sorry I was unclear, but on each webpage, there is many "pages" that belong to a book. But everything is all on one webpage.

Comment: @the_ Can you give an example of the html that is submitting to the `update` action? That's probably the best clue for us as to what's not working for you.

Comment: @stringsn88keys, I refactored the question, is it simpler?

Comment: Could you please show what the `answer_fields` template looks like and what your `link_to_add_fields` helper does?

Comment: do you want to save for the user or just the device?

Comment: @OlivierLance, It's the same as the railscast I linked. But I'll add it to the question as well.

Comment: @the_ the railscast is for subscribed users only ;)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so as you can note, when you render fields for a question it either:

- already exists on the `questions` collection
- is added as a new object *via* the `link_to_add_fields` method

Each question form builder will have a `child_index` that will either be the question's id itself, or the `object_id` of the newly created (but unsaved) question object. This means that each field you add for a specific question is nested within a dedicated hash, allowing you to associate different values for identically named inputs to each questions.

So you already have a few values associated to each question... what you should do, is add a hidden input field to `question_fields` that will store the question's position:

```
f.hidden_field :position, class: 'question-position'
```

In your javascript code, create a function that will devise the position of each question within the sortable list. Here's what it could look like (I have not tested this code but I believe it should work):

```
function refreshPositions()
{
    $('.question-position').each(function() {
        var idx = $(this).closest('li').index();
        $(this).val(idx);
    });
}
```

This will iterate through all hidden inputs with class `question-position`, find the position of their parent `<li>` within the sortable list and assign the position to the hidden field value. Doing so, you have a position value associated to each question.

Use this function with the jQueryUI sortable events `create` and `update` to maintain an up-to-date value for each question position:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    create: refreshPositions,
    update: refreshPositions
});
```

(this is valid as we do not expect any arguments given to `refreshPositions`, otherwise you'd need to use an anonymous function for each handler and call `refreshPositions` from there)

Given this setup, when you submit the form you will now receive your questions in your Rails app with a `position` field that you can save into your `Question` model and use to order the questions later on.